# Can i use "the same" as a pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

He lent me some money on the condition that i should return (**the same/it**) before November.

Is it formal to use "The same" when we want to refer the previously stated thing after a conjunction or in next sentence.

Thank you.

Comment: It’s not formal, it’s legalese. In normal writing or conversation it could thus have a slightly rude connotation.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but by saying "the same," he is establishing the condition that you are to return the exact same money to him before November, not the same amount of money but the exact same bills.  If he, for example, lent you a one dollar bill with the serial number 1348, he is requiring that same dollar bill with the serial number 1348 be returned to him, not any other dollar bill.  If the condition is that you are to return not the exact same money but the same amount of money, you'd say "it."

Comment: I know "it" technically means the same thing, so call it idiomatic, for we nonetheless say "it" to merely mean the same amount, while saying "the same" instead of "it" would be strange enough that it would suggest you mean something different by "the same," and the obvious difference is that you are making the unusual request of getting the exact same money back, not just equivalent money in an equal amount.

Comment: Thank you Xanne and Benjamin for your help. :)

Comment: I'm afraid Benjamin here is wrong. "The same" does not mean "exactly the same one". It simply refers to what has been referenced earlier. While it appears to be common in Indian English, in other variants you'd say "it". (And *it* **could** refer to "exactly the same" as well, if the previous reference was to something which could be identified rather than just generic "money": "I lent him a 50c coin on the condition that he should return it later on.")

Comment: So, Does it mean that i can use "the same" in any such sentences when i'm talking about the previously mentioned thing. Actually this sentence came in my exam, some people says that "the same" cannot  replace pronoun" it". Please tell me is it right? My exam demands proper british grammar.

Comment: This isn't a question of grammar. Both are grammatical but so is 'angry green clouds smell nonchalantly'

Comment: *"What will you have for dessert?" "I'll have the pie." "Very good. And you?" "I'll have **the same**."* The use of *the same* is common. It's context that determines the nature of the referent. It's a perfectly normal part of English. Whether it should be used in a *formal* context is a matter of opinion. And it depends on the particular sentence if *the same* can be interchanged with *it*.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jason